# Modified shift operator is compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, compact-operators

> For the operator $$T(\eta_j) = \frac{\eta_{j+1}}{j}$$ on Hilbert Space $H$ where $(\eta_j)$ is a basis. Show it is compact.

Can this work?

Define $$f = (\eta_j)_{j \geq 1}$$

$$T_N(f) =  \left(\frac{1}{j} \eta_{j+1}\right)_{j=1..N}$$

$$T(f) = \left(\frac{1}{j} \eta_{j+1}\right)_{j =1..\infty}$$

So $\| T_N (f) - T(f) \|^2 = \left\| \sum_{j = N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j} \eta_{j+1} \right\|^2 \leq \sum_{j = n + 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2} < \epsilon/4$

since $\sum_{j} \frac{1}{j^2}$ converges.

(alternative proof in [here pg5](http://www.math.umn.edu/~bahra004/for-real/real2-hw3.pdf), but there is an assumption on orthonormality).

Comment: $f_k = (\eta_j)_{j\geq 1}$ looks like $f_k$ is the basis $(\eta_j)$ for each $k \in \mathbb N$... ?

Comment: @JonWarneke, I am making a lot of typos, but I think we can even drop the index $k$

Comment: What are the $c_{j,k}$?

Comment: @JonWarneke, should be good now.

Comment: You seem to be making at least some assumption like $\| \eta_j \| \leq 1$ in your last step. Is it really the case that $(\eta_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ is not an orthonormal basis? In a separable Hilbert space (like this one, since we have a countable basis) there always exists an orthonormal basis, and we almost exclusively work in one. If not, some type of integral transform is usually used to change bases.

Comment: @JonWarneke, I assumed its bounded. But I understand where you are coming form.